# Recover deleted comment

Tags: discussion, status-completed, deleted-comments, specific-comment

Is it possible to recover a deleted comment?

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060992/) a user (freeflow) apparently (from other comments) suggested a solution in his comment, but the comment got deleted before I had a chance to read it. Can it be recovered?